# Symfony compiler pass get Monolog package information

Tags: php, symfony

Using Symfony 6.3

I have created custom Monolog handler to fit our needs. Basically log DEBUG only when debugging is turned on for user.

```yaml
// packages/monolog.yaml
monolog:
    handlers:
        conditional_debug:
            type: service
            id: App\Log\Handler\DebugLogHandler
            handler: info_log
```

```php
class DebugLogHandler extends Handler
{
    public function __construct(
        private \Closure|HandlerInterface $handler,
        private bool $bubble = false,
        private int $bufferSize = 0,
    ) {
    }
}
```

Now problem is that this `$handler` is not passed into. So unless there is other way, I am planing on writing compiler pass that would take Monolog configuration and apply it to my handler:

```php
class LogHandlerCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container): void
    {
        $definition = $container->getDefinition(DebugLogHandler::class);

        $monologConfig = $container->/* -> ??? <- */;
    }
}
```

---

*Question* is how to get `[packages] monolog->handlers->condition_debug` definition inside compiler pass?